# How to extract the similarities between two strings

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have two strings in two different sentences:

string 1: `30 mutation alanine for valine`

string 2: `alanine at position 30`

is there away to find the similarities between them as it is clear
they both have 30 and alanine using regular expressions for example?

Comment: We aren't biologists you'll have to show us example strings.

Comment: @JoelDavis the OP _has_ shown examples of the strings.

Comment: @terdon I posted that while on mobile. I'm seeing it now but the backtick markup doesn't show up on the mobile site so I thought that "alanine at position 30" was a descriptive sentence than literal. Is that something the admins can fix in the stylesheet? I'm willing to be the three people who upvoted probably didn't see the markup either.

Comment: @JoelDavis I added the markup, it wasn't there. That's probably why you didn't see it :). It should be clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you could do is check for words that appear in both strings:

```
$ comm -12 <(sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<$str1 | sort) <(sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<$str2 | sort )
30
alanine
```

#### Explanation

- The `comm command` compares files. With the `-1` and `-2` flags, it will print those lines that are found in *both* files.
- `sed 's/ /\n/g' <<<$str1 | sort` : This simply replaces all spaces with newlines in `$str1`, printing to standard output which is then passed through `sort` because `comm` needs its input files to be sorted. For more on the `<<<$var` format, see [Bash: Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).
- The `<(command)` format is called process substitution, more on that [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

The final result of the command above will be a list of all words that appear in both strings.

Comment: I'd rather use `tr " " "\n"` instead of sed.

Comment: Based on the suggestion by Emmanuel:

`comm -12 <(tr ' ' '\n'<<<$str1 | sort) <(tr ' ' '\n'<<<$str2 | sort)`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `wdiff` can help you? Put the strings into two files and then compare them with `wdiff`:

```
echo "30 mutation alanine for valine" > file1
echo "alanine at position 30" > file2
wdiff -t file1 file2
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way with plain regex as what you are doing is a bit complex.

In a language like [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) you can [split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split) the strings into an array of space delimited words via a regex (`\s+`) and get the [intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-26) (`&`) of the two resulting arrays.

```ruby
"30 mutation alanine for valine".split( /\s+/ ) & "alanine at position 30".split( /\s+/ )
=> ["30", "alanine"]
```

Whitespace is actually the default for split in Ruby so this can be shortened to

```ruby
"30 mutation alanine for valine".split & "alanine at position 30".split
```

Comment: Ruby is a gem :)

Comment: hah! (apparently i can't just hah!)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[$i]++}}
    END {
        for(i in a) {
            if(a[i] > 1) {
                print i
            }
        }
    }' file1 file2
30
alanine
```